# Error when add Ads with StartApp

Tags: android, ads, startapp

I add Ads to my application as setup in document of StartApp:

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />

<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />

<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.FullScreenActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
```

My application oly have one activity:

```
    StartAppSDK.init(this, "***", true);
```

When I start app from dim mode: there is a crash:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {***/com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I have more question is:

I want a banner and a fullbanner show but not concurrent: 
Ex: `From dim state => fullbaner, close fullbanner => bottom banner show.`

How do I implement it ?

Comment: add `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have a stupid bug. I put **activity** declare out of **application** tag.

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Change theme style

```
<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
```

to

```
<activity
        android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
```